# multipoint boundary value ode with varying coefficients in matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a second order differential equation given as:

```
d²u/dz²=a+bu, where a and b are constants that vary in different intervals and z∈[0,Zn]

Intervals are given as I1:z∈[0,Z1), I2:z∈[Z1, Z2), ..., I(n):z∈[Z(n-1), Z(n)] and {a,b} constants varies as {a1,b1} in I1, {a2,b2} in I2,...,{an,bn} in I(n).
```

Boundary condition is given as u(z=0)=U0, u(z=Zn)=Umax.

A continuous graph of u vs z is required.

I thought of using bvp5c in matlab but bvp5c can solve multipoint boundary value problems where a = a0 < a1 < a2 < ... < an = b in the interval [a,b]. The points a1,a2, ... ,an–1 represent interfaces that divide [a,b] into regions. The problem is my constants(a,b in above ode) is also varying in different intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. If you read the bvp5c docs, you will see that it takes a function handle (odefun) which takes the z, and u arguments. Simply return the correct value for the RHS based on value of the argument z. Note that you have to convert your 2nd order equation to a 1st order one.

```
du/dz = v
dv/dz = a(z) + b(z)u
```

You need to return the vector [v, a(z) + b(z)u] from the two arguments z and [u,v] that your odefun will be called with.